# A single word synonym for "A person not to mess with"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word synonym for **"A person not to mess with"** without explicitly evoking a specific reason, as in "fearsome" for example.

Example in a sentence:

> Kidd was an ***`unfuckwithable`*** pirate for my lack of a better
>   placeholder.

Comment: I dunno. I like your word.

Comment: How about BAMF?

Comment: "chucknorrisy"?

Comment: BigBadJohn ?  This goes back a ways.

Comment: I can't decide which of Jim Croce's songs to use as a joke. Best not to I guess.

Comment: Is 'wife' an option?

Comment: It's a great question, and your created word is **perfect**.  Bravo.  Note that the somewhat archaic word "redoubtable" does mean precisely unfuckwithable, but it sounds old-fashioned.   Fearsome is OK but doesn't sound as cool as unfuckwithable.  Note that the common phrasing "John was a person not to be messed with" is a common approach.

Comment: Jim.    (as in "you don't tug on Superman's cape", etc).  Or, more seriously, "volatile"?

Comment: What's wrong with "fearsome"?

Comment: If we think that his unfuckwithableness (we Germans have a tendency of susbstantivation, sorry) is showing in the fear he instills in his opponents, there is a whole bag of words like *terrifying*, jpmc's *fearsome*, *intimidating* etc.

Comment: @Peter: substantivisation is great, but I think _unfuckwithability_ is more natural in English.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I'd go with **Formidable**. According to Cambridge Online:

> **Formidable:** *adjective:* causing you to have fear or respect for something or someone because that thing or person is large, powerful, or difficult:

Comparison with other answers so far:

- **Redoubtable**: Means pretty much the same thing, but is more archaic.
- **No-nonsense**: Means the person *doesn't mess around*. This is not the
  same as *not to be messed with*
- **Badass:** Is informal, and directly suggests the person is violent.
  Formidable doesn't directly suggest violence. If you are a formidable
  chess player, then your opponents should have fear or respect of your
  skills; but you are not a badass because there is nothing violent
  about this. Another difference is "That guy is a badass!" usually
  means something like "That guy is cool!" and is usually positive, while
  "That guy is formidable" is not obviously positive or negative.
- **Awesome:** The word has an archaic meaning of 'inspiring awe' which is
  similar to respect. However the modern meaning of the word is just
  slang for 'good'. In fact due to [language degradation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IJRQbAuXVM) it's a
  pretty weak word for good.
- **Terrific:** The archaic meaning is 'inspiring terror' which is like
  respect but different. The modern meaning is again just 'good' but
  even then it can sound a bit *pip pip cheerio old chum British
  colonialism.*

The formidable trees in Pokemon are formidable because they **cannot be cut down**. They are stronger than the other cuttable trees. If the stronger trees appeared as obstacles there would be no way through and the came would be impossible to finish.

Comment: I believe this is the closest to what I wanted, but I can't help but have a positive connotation for "formidable" because of French!

Comment: Yeah it's a bit of a *robinet*. The 'goodness' of the English word is just the 'good at whatever it is that inspires fear/respect'.

Comment: ***Awesome*** (or ***terrific***) would be quite good alternatives for *causing you to have fear or respect for something or someone*, especially the former (which also fits your *good at whatever it is…* definition well).

Comment: I agree with this answer if the person "not to be messed with" is generally assumed to only use above-board tactics.  Formidable opponents generally don't cheat to win, whereas a person "not to be messed with" generally keeps all options on the table...

Comment: You can also find a few more common, similar words that haven't been mentioned yet in [a thesaurus entry](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/formidable)

Comment: In Pokemon games, the phrase "a large formidable tree" is very typical, and I have never anticipated it like an `unfuckwithable` tree. In the contrary, these trees invite you to heabdutt them, in order for a wild Pokemon to fall down, and battle! More importantly, in these games, there are usually trees that can result in a serious obstacle for you (and the word `formidable` is not used in the games to describe them).

Comment: I like redoutable more. In every usage of the words I have ever seen, formidable is more of a good quality, seldom associated with prowess in physical altercations (which is, I believe, what OP needs). Redoutable however is almost aways chosen when a more aggressive connotation is needed.

Comment: @Daron ... what's a *robinet*? Google only gave me birds, faucets and some obscure military device...

Comment: @Quentin it's French for **tap**.

Comment: @Outman that I knew, but I don't get what Daron means by it.

Comment: A *Robinet* is an example of what are sometimes called *faux-amis*. The word sounds like the English Robin but is actually the French word for Faucet.

Comment: Funny how "awesome" and "terrible" were synonyms for centuries and now couldn't be bigger antonyms. A couple of words with *very* different connotations if you are writing historically.

Comment: Yes words awesome and awful have the same origin but now have different meanings.

Comment: @Outman think of formidable as enhancing the quality of whatever comes after it. A formidable opponent is nothing but positive for you, but it is quite positive for your opponent. The same goes for a formidable pirate, it's positive for the pirate but quite the opposite for trade ships.

Answer (score 34):

I sense someone labeled a **badass** should be avoided!

- Kidd was a **badass** pirate for my lack of a better placeholder.

badass  [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/badass)

> If you describe someone as a badass, you mean that they are very tough
>   or violent.

Comment: What I'm exactly looking for is to describe someone solely based on the factor of unfuckwithability alone without explaining why. It's not only the tough or the badass, you could also say that "Kidd was a Machiavellian" or "malignant" for example.

Comment: @Outman even after 4 answers and your comment, it is more unclear what your are seeking, especially a single word for such.

Comment: This fits the question better because it's a **noun** not an adjective.

Comment: A badass is generally seen as a compliment - you wouldn't use it for someone you didn't like. Saying they weren't to be messed with covers all areas.

Answer (score 18):

Another possiblity is **daunting**,

> tending to overwhelm or intimidate

which would seem a pretty good description of a well-known bad-ass.

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever seen "daunting" describe a person. Is that usage common?

Comment: @piojo - Nope. I have seen it but not often. Seems like a good use, though.

Comment: _It seemed like a daunting task to overcome his opponent._ Daunting to me also conveys that something is do-able, but discouraging.

Comment: @piojo Common enough.  “Joe was widely regarded as a daunting opponent, due to his history of effortlessly decapitating dozens of highly skilled adversaries in personal combat.”

Comment: Maybe it's regional, or it depends on the genre of books you read. My first thought was that this is definitely incorrect usage, but I'm willing to believe it's a matter of style. (I read it as the opposite of personification: referring to a person as a situation, much akin to nouning a verb.)

Answer (score 10):

**[redoubtable](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/redoubtable)**:

> very strong, especially in character; producing respect and a little fear in others:
>
> *Tonight he faces the most redoubtable opponent of his boxing career.*

[Cambridge]

If you say Kidd was a redoubtable pirate, you say he was formidable as well as someone to be feared (not to be messed with).

Answer (score 2):

The word you are looking for is a compound adjective, in an attributive use: "no-nonsense"

> Kidd was a no-nonsense pirate.

Cambridge Dictionary Online:

> no-nonsense;
>   adjective [ before noun ] UK ​  /ˌnəʊˈnɒn.səns/ US ​  /ˌnoʊˈnɑːn.sens/
>   ​
>   practical and serious, and only interested in doing what is necessary or achieving what is intended, without silly ideas or methods:
>   a no-nonsense manner/leader
>   a no-nonsense approach to child-rearing

Comment: My grandma was no-nonsense... I don't think that word evokes the picture that OP is trying to draw with his pirate.

Answer (score 2):

invulnerable or 
invincible

Both are very strong words.

Blackbeard was thought to be ***invincible*** even some time after he was decapitated, as it is legend that his body searched for his head, and his head continued to laugh and talk.

Comment: Hi Mike, this might end up a good answer but at the moment it's just an unsubstantiated personal opinion. An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. Can I suggest you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a published definition of the two words (linked to the source) and why they are "very strong"? For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Aposematic** describes the effect the pirate has on other people by **signaling danger**.

From Mariam Webster Online:

> **Aposematic:** adjective: **being conspicuous and serving to warn**

This particular behavior is known from the zooligical sciences and accurately describes the "not to mess with" signal. From Encyclopaedia Britannica online, emphasis added:

> **Aposematic mechanism**, biological means by which a dangerous, or noxious, organism ***advertises its dangerous nature*** to potential predators. **The predator, having recognized the dangerous organism as an unfavourable prey, thereupon desists from attacking it**. Aposematic, or warning, mechanisms have evolved along with protective systems; it is advantageous for the protected organism **not to risk the injury that is likely to occur** in even a successfully repelled attack by a predator.
>
> The most common aposematic mechanism is the possession of bright,
>   contrasting colours, such as the black and yellow of many wasps and
>   the red of ladybird beetles. Other organisms, such as the North
>   American rattlesnakes, employ acoustic warning systems.

Answer (score 2):

### Trouble

Example usage:

"That one, he's trouble."

Not sure if that usage is current, but it was very common when I was growing up in the 60's and 70's.

Comment: That's a good word! But consider you might say "That little girl is trouble" and not mean the same as "she's not to be messed with".

Comment: @Daron Yes, the usage varies with context.

Answer (score 0):

**dreadnought**

```
[2]b : one that is among the largest or most powerful of its kind
```

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dreadnought

Not in common usage